# File Provider Extension fails to start on iOS 9 & 10 when built with Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9

I have the pre-iOS 11 Action + Document + File Provider extensions. The issue I see is the following:

When my app is built with Xcode 8, File Provider works fine on all iOSes.

When my app is built with **Xcode 9** (no code changes), File Provider **works fine on iOS 11, but fails to start on iOS 9 and 10**.

The document picker and action extensions work fine everywhere.

I need to build on Xcode 9 because I want to use classes unavailable in Xcode 8.

Here are device logs of successful (Xcode 8) and unsuccessful (Xcode 9) attempts to register the File Provider Extension when the main app is started. Similar messages appear when another app tries to call the extension.

**Xcode 9 on iOS 10**

```
installd(MobileSystemServices)[42] <Notice>: 0x16e107000 -[MIContainer makeContainerLiveReplacingContainer:reason:withError:]: Made container live for com.companyname.appname.fileprovider at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/5B502EFD-DFA7-4F23-BCCE-EBF63F455B98
lsd(MobileCoreServices)[75] <Notice>: Found extensionPointData dict <com.apple.fileprovider-ui> for <private>
lsd(MobileCoreServices)[75] <Notice>: Found extensionPointData dict <com.apple.fileprovider-nonui> for <private>
SpringBoard(UserNotificationsServer)[49] <Notice>: [com.companyname.appname] Application installed using default data provider
SpringBoard(UserNotificationsServer)[49] <Notice>: Create new default data providers
fileproviderd(MobileCoreServices)[21] <Notice>: LaunchServices observer: Installed plugins <private>
fileproviderd(Foundation)[21] <Notice>: discovered extensions
assertiond[59] <Notice>: Ignoring assertion request named "com.apple.extension.session" from <BSProcessHandle: 0x10022bb30; fileproviderd:21; valid: YES> because process { pid 224; bundleID (null) } is unknown.
fileproviderd(Foundation)[21] <Notice>: calling plugIn beginUsing:
fileproviderd(PlugInKit)[21] <Notice>: connection to plug-in <private>(C96A6048-676A-4B17-8DEF-983B0BEA5656) lost
fileproviderd(PlugInKit)[21] <Error>: Hub connection error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.companyname.appname.fileprovider" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.companyname.appname.fileprovider}
fileproviderd(Foundation)[21] <Notice>: PlugInKit error in beginUsing:
fileproviderd[21] <Fault>: [ERROR] Extension request failed. Error: <private>
fileproviderd[21] <Fault>: [ERROR] Error registering file provider extension <private>: <private>.
fileproviderd[21] <Notice>: [NOTICE] Trying to register file provider extension <private> again. Tries left: 2
fileproviderd(Foundation)[21] <Notice>: killing invalid plugIn
fileproviderd(Foundation)[21] <Notice>: completed calling plugIn beginUsing: for pid: 0
assertiond[59] <Notice>: Ignoring assertion request named "com.apple.extension.session" from <BSProcessHandle: 0x10022bb30; fileproviderd:21; valid: YES> because process { pid 224; bundleID (null) } is unknown.
fileproviderd(Foundation)[21] <Notice>: calling plugIn beginUsing:
fileproviderd(PlugInKit)[21] <Error>: plug-in <private> pre-screen sees activating state
fileproviderd(PlugInKit)[21] <Notice>: connection to plug-in <private>(C96A6048-676A-4B17-8DEF-983B0BEA5656) lost
fileproviderd(PlugInKit)[21] <Error>: Hub connection error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.companyname.appname.fileprovider" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.companyname.appname.fileprovider}
fileproviderd(Foundation)[21] <Notice>: PlugInKit error in beginUsing:
fileproviderd[21] <Fault>: [ERROR] Extension request failed. Error: <private>
fileproviderd(Foundation)[21] <Notice>: killing invalid plugIn
fileproviderd[21] <Fault>: [ERROR] Error registering file provider extension <private>: <private>.
```

**Xcode 8 on iOS 10**

```
fileproviderd(Foundation)[21] <Notice>: discovered extensions
installd(MobileSystemServices)[42] <Notice>: 0x16e107000 -[MIInstallableBundle _refreshUUIDForContainer:withError:]: Data container for com.companyname.appname.fileprovider is now at /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/8B44BA26-5F62-465E-B40D-A0FE9F4277B1
lsd(MobileCoreServices)[75] <Notice>: Found extensionPointData dict <com.apple.fileprovider-ui> for <private>
lsd(MobileCoreServices)[75] <Notice>: Found extensionPointData dict <com.apple.fileprovider-nonui> for <private>
SpringBoard(UserNotificationsServer)[49] <Notice>: [com.companyname.appname] Application installed using default data provider
SpringBoard(UserNotificationsServer)[49] <Notice>: Create new default data providers
fileproviderd(Foundation)[21] <Notice>: discovered extensions
fileproviderd(MobileCoreServices)[21] <Notice>: LaunchServices: Waiting on mutex for local DB to be updated
fileproviderd(MobileCoreServices)[21] <Notice>: LaunchServices observer: Uninstalled plugins <private>
fileproviderd(MobileCoreServices)[21] <Notice>: LaunchServices observer: Installed plugins <private>
assertiond[59] <Notice>: Ignoring assertion request named "com.apple.extension.session" from <BSProcessHandle: 0x10022bb30; fileproviderd:21; valid: YES> because process { pid 224; bundleID (null) } is unknown.
fileproviderd(Foundation)[21] <Notice>: calling plugIn beginUsing:
FileProvider(ADAL)[319] <Notice>: ADAL version 2.3.1
kernel(Sandbox)[0] <Notice>: SandboxViolation: FileProvider(319) deny(1) file-read-data /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application
kernel(Sandbox)[0] <Notice>: SandboxViolation: FileProvider(319) deny(1) file-read-data /private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup
fileproviderd(Foundation)[21] <Notice>: completed calling plugIn beginUsing: for pid: 319
FileProvider[319] <Notice>: ACFileProvider - "init" [319]:0x13dd560b0. Constructor
```

Any ideas what's causing this and how I can get it fixed?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File providers built with Xcode 9 won't work on iOS 9 and 10. It's an Apple bug mentioned in iOS 11.1 Beta release notes. Hopefully they'll fix it at some point as per their documentation it's supposed to work.

**Update:**
Fixed in Xcode 9.1.

Comment: From @Ben "This problem seems to be fixed in Xcode 9.1." (pasted due to them having a low score)